# Create the most simple/basic deep network where variable initialization does matter a lot

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create the most basic and simple neural network to simulate a situation where the random initialization of the variables matters a lot.
So if I run the network and the initialization over and over again the network will not converge well, unless the random initialization hit the sweet spot.

So basically trying to come up with the most simple example of a non-convex cost function to simulate a situation of non-convergence.

Comment: If your data can linearly be separable use simple SVM because its cost function is convex, if it is not separable linearly use non-linear svm

Comment: I am talking about deep neural networks. I want to try and create a network and to find some problem that the network will only converge for a given initialization, and will stuck (not converge) when trying different initializations.

Comment: for deep nets you can not find convex cost function

Comment: So you are claiming that I can reach the same global solution no matter what variable initialization I have.

Comment: The initialization happens just once and then learning begins. Whenever your learning stucks means your net is small if the accuracy is low. So you have to add more units or layers. What I told you was this that whenever you use neural nets, the cost function can not be convex. In contrast, the cost function that SVM uses is convex, and after using that and finding the minimum, it would be the best possible answer for the current architecture and it won't have better accuracy even if you change your initialization.